# The PDFBox2.0 trans to image,but the "org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio" cann't find

Tags: pdfbox

On the apache PDFBox web sit,http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html ,the PDF Rendering example.

```
ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (pageCounter++) + ".png", 300);
```

the ImageIOUtil cann't find.help me,Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in the pdfbox-tools package, as mentioned on that web page:

```
ImageIOUtil has been moved into the org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio package.
```

See pdfbox-tools on the [download page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html).

For maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

(the version may be higher at the time you read this)